# Where do I start with these set theory proofs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume that $A \neq \emptyset$, and that $B = \mathcal{P}(A)$. Assume that $S \subset B$.

(a) Prove that if $x \in S$, then $x \subset \bigcup S$ (union of S) . (This proves that $\bigcup S$ is an upper bound of $S$)

(b) Prove that if $D$ is any upper bound of $S$, then $\bigcup S \subset D$. 
((a) and (b) together prove that $\bigcup S$ is the least upper bound of $S$)

Comment: I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Nadia: Always start by reminding yourself of the relevant definitions. In most of the elementary exercises they’re just about all you need in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (a) is just a matter of checking the definitions; I’ll go ahead and do it to get you started, but it is the kind of question that can be answered just by ‘following your nose’, i.e., doing the most straightforward thing, and you want to learn to recognize those pretty quickly.

By definition

$$\bigcup S=\{y:\exists s\in S(y\in s)\}\;;$$

if $y\in x\in S$, then in the definition we can take $s=x$ and see that there is indeed an $s\in S$ such that $y\in s$, and therefore $y\in\bigcup S$. Thus, every element of $x$ is an element of $\bigcup S$, and therefore $x\subseteq\bigcup S$.

For (b), suppose that $D$ is an upper bound for $S$; this means that $x\subseteq D$ for each $x\in S$. Now suppose that $\bigcup S\nsubseteq D$, and derive a contradiction; it’s not hard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this.  Like Brian says, this comes down to expanding definitions and logic.  But I'll do it a bit more formally... :-)

For (a) you have to prove $\;\langle \forall X : X \in S : X \subseteq \bigcup S \rangle\;$. I would start with the $\;X \subseteq \bigcup S\;$ part and try to work my way back: for all $\;X\;$,
\begin{align}
& X \subseteq \bigcup S \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y : y \in X : y \in \bigcup S \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\bigcup\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y : y \in X : \langle \exists V : V \in S : y \in V \rangle \rangle \\
\Leftarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"choose $\;V:=X\;$ -- inspired by our goal $\;X \in S\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y : y \in X : X \in S \land y \in X \rangle \\
\Leftarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic"} \\
& X \in S \\
\end{align}

For part (b) you have to prove $\;D\text{ is an upper bound of }S \;\Rightarrow\; \bigcup S \subseteq D\;$ for all $\;D\;$, i.e., $$\langle \forall D : \langle \forall X : X \in S : X \subseteq D \rangle : \bigcup S \subseteq D \rangle$$

This can be done similarly, by starting with $\;\bigcup S \subseteq D\;$, expanding the same two definitions, and applying predicate logic.  The key steps will be
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall y : \langle \exists V : V \in S : y \in V \rangle : y \in D \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: apply DeMorgan to convert $\;\exists V\;$ in antecedent to $\;\forall V\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y,V : V \in S \land y \in V : y \in D \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: move $\;V \in S\;$ outside of $\;\forall y\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall V : V \in S : \langle \forall y : y \in V : y \in D \rangle \rangle \\
\end{align}

And the conclusion will be that in (b) you can prove that $\;\langle \forall X : X \in S : X \subseteq D \rangle\;$ and $\;\bigcup S \subseteq D\;$ are actually equivalent.

Finally, note that we don't need the assumption that $\;A \ne ∅\;$.